# Boost spirit fixed point as integer parser

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I have the following parser,

```
    #define PRICE_MULT 10000
    qi::uint_parser<uint32_t, 10, 1, 6> int_part;
    qi::uint_parser<uint32_t, 10, 1, 6> dec_part;

    qi::rule<Iterator, uint64_t()> fixed_point =
         (int_part >> "." >> dec_part )[qi::_val = qi::_1 * PRICE_MULT + qi::_2];


    m_wire_msg = ( qi::as_string[*qi::alpha] >> "," // symbol
                >> qi::ulong_long >> ","        // symbol seq num
                >> qi::ulong_long >> ","        // order id
                >> (fixed_point | qi::ulong_) >> ","
                >> qi::uint_ >> ","                   // volume
                >> qi::char_ >> ","                   // side
                >> +qi::space >> ","                  // firm id
                >> qi::ushort_                        // parity split
```

But it fails to parse,

```
"AAPL,1192544,16044086616349464,157.47,100,S,     ,0"
```

Specifically, the 157.47 can sometimes be whole numbers, for eg. 157 on its own, which is why i'm using "(fixed_point | qi::ulong_)".

But parsing fails, which I don't quite understand. Ideally is should also parse the following correctly,

```
"AAPL,1192544,16044086616349464,157,100,S,     ,0"
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use optional parser to not fail if there is no fractional part.

Also you had `PRICE_MULT` with 4 zeros, but `dec_part` was allowed up to 6 digits.

```
#define PRICE_MULT 10000
qi::uint_parser<std::uint32_t, 10, 1, 6> int_part;
qi::uint_parser<std::uint32_t, 10, 1, 4> dec_part;

qi::rule<Iterator, std::uint64_t()> fixed_point =
      int_part[qi::_val = qi::_1 * PRICE_MULT]
    >> -('.' >> dec_part[qi::_val += qi::_1]);
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/H46ujDgJ57gyE69I

The right fixed point parser can look like this:

```
constexpr std::uint64_t lut[] = { 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000 };
constexpr int frac_digits = 6;
qi::uint_parser<std::uint32_t, 10, 1, 6> const int_part;
qi::uint_parser<std::uint32_t, 10, 1, frac_digits> const dec_part;
qi::rule<Iterator, std::uint64_t()> fixed_point
    = int_part[qi::_val = qi::_1 * lut[frac_digits]]           // parse integer part and save multiplied by lut[frac_digits]
   >> ( !qi::lit('.')                                          // do not fail on missing fractional part
      | ('.' >>  qir::iter_pos >> dec_part >> qir::iter_pos)[  // parse fraction and save/syntesize iterators before and after
                    qi::_val += qi::_2 * phx::ref(lut)[        // multiple fraction by lookuped pow10 value
                                            frac_digits - (qi::_3 - qi::_1)]]
        >> *qi::digit);                                        // consume unparsed digits
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/mtdMDPzB2RjPxQlD

```
input          result
=====          ======
123            123000000 
123.0          123000000
123.4          123400000
123.45         123450000
123.456        123456000
123.4567       123456700
123.45678      123456780
123.456789     123456789
123.456789123  123456789
123.           fail
.123           fail
```

Comment: Wouldn't this parse repeated `,` as if it were just one? Also, can you describe what you changed? What about it is the fix? What was the problem?

Comment: Yes, you are right about multiple commas. Simplified answer to the actual question.

Comment: oh ya you're right. PRICE_MULT should be 1000000. and thanks alot for the suggested solution!

Comment: Here is a working example https://wandbox.org/permlink/H46ujDgJ57gyE69I

Comment: Thanks! i realised i made a mistake

Comment: Can you see my further question below?

Comment: You have added an answer. I updated my answer with a parser that will do what you want to achieve.

Comment: ah very cool! thank you very much once again for enlightening me on the correct way to do things.

Comment: One last question, if some fields can either be a number of empty, for example "AAPL,10,P" or 'AAPL,,P" , what's the best way to parse either 10 or the empty field and provide a default value of 0 for it?

Comment: 1) Do not ask questions in comments, edit the original or open a new one. 2) It is better to open a new question even if it is in the same domain https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts 3) This question was answered multiple times e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690780/boost-spirit-qi-integer-with-default-value-on-literal `(qi::int | qi::attr(0))` should do the work.

Comment: well noted! will post a new question in future!

Answer (score 0):

is the following the best way if i want to make 157.47 be 1574700, by multiplying 10000?

```
m_fixed_point = m_int_part[qi::_val = qi::_1 * PRICE_MULT] >>
-("." >> -(m_digit[qi::_val += qi::_1 * 1000])
>> -(m_digit[qi::_val += qi::_1 * 100])
>> -(m_digit[qi::_val += qi::_1 * 10])
>> -(m_digit[qi::_val += qi::_1 ])
);
```